# how to solve UnhaldedPromiseRejectionWarning when rejecting a promise

Tags: javascript, promise, unhandled-promise-rejection

I am new to JavaScript and I am learning about promises. I created a simple script similar to the example I was given that checks whether a table can be booked and resolves/rejects the promise if it can or can't at the specified time.

If the time specified is free, the promise is resolved with no issues, but if it is rejected, I get the error

```
(node:8300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Sorry, we won't have a table in  4 hours
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:8300) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8300) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

From google, it seems I should have a try and catch block for the accept and reject, but I am unsure how to do this with the if-else statement.

If anyone can help explain why I am receiving an error and/or what a better way of writing this script, it would be greatly appreciated.

```
> let bookedTimes = [1,2,4]
> 
> bookTable = (time) => {
>     console.log(`I would like to book a table in ${time} hours`)
>     return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
>         console.log('Checking available tables...')
>         if(bookedTimes.includes(time)){
>             const error = `Sorry, we won't have a table in  ${time} hours`
>             setTimeout(() => {
>               reject(error)
>               console.log(error)
>             }, 2000)
>           } 
>           else {
>             const success = `Success! Your reservation will be ready in ${time} hours`
>             setTimeout(() => {
>               resolve(success)
>               console.log(success)
>             }, 2000)
>             
>           }
>     }) }
> 
> 
> bookTable(4)
```

Comment: `bookTable(4)` ---> `bookTable(4).catch(err => console.log(err))`

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `bookTable`, a promise is returned, which would either resolve or reject.

Just like any other promise, you need to be ready for both cases.

```
bookTable(4).then(resolveValue=>...).catch(rejectValue=>...) // specify in then and catch what you want to do with those values.
```

Your error comes when you don't have any plan in case the promise rejects, which in above line is `catch` method.

An alternative way to handle this is using **try and catch** as you indicated.

Comment: Ah thank you, I didn't realize my method wasn't handling the rejection.